# AngularJS ng-if directive briefly renders even when condition is false before removing element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ng-if

In the below template, I would expect the script tag to never render, and the alert script to never execute. However it does.

```
<div ng-if="false">
    <script>alert('should not run')</script>
    Should not appear
</div>
```

This is causing us huge performance problems on mobile devices as we wrap large DOM and directive structures in `ng-if`s with the expectation they will not render when the condition is false.

I have also tested `ng-switch` which behaves in the same manner.

Is this expected behaviour? Is there a way to avoid the unnecessary render?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hLw0nady/)

Comment: Have you read this? https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3954

Comment: try <div ng-if="'false'">

Answer (score 8):

It may seem backward, but `ngIf` deals more with the removal of DOM, rather than the addition. Before the controller finishes instantiating, the DOM still exists. This is generally a good thing, and allows you to have graceful degradation for users without JS (or, alternatively, an initial loading state).

If you don't want the inner DOM to render, place it in a directive (either its own directive, or via `ng-include`) or in a view.

**Example 1 (understanding why the script runs):**

To help yourself understand the flow a bit better, you can update the example to instead be:

```
<div ng-if="false">
    {{"Should not appear"}}
    <script>alert('should not run')</script>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hLw0nady/6/embedded/result/

You will notice that when the alert pops up, Angular has not yet interpolated "Should not appear" (it appears in its braces). After you dismiss the alert, however, it disappears.

**Example 2 (how to prevent the alert):**

An example of hiding the code that "should not run" in a `directive` can be viewed here: https://jsfiddle.net/hLw0nady/4/

In this example, only if you replace `ng-if="false"` with `ng-if="true"` will you get your alert.

Answer (score 0):

I think that false expression is not well converted to angular false. 
I can prove this by setting:

```
<div ng-if="!true">
```

Which doesn't render text in current div. 
Anyway, it executes alert, i suppose it is executed before angular runs, that's why.

Comment: Still won't work: https://jsfiddle.net/hLw0nady/5/ . You don't understand the problem. No matter what you place in this `ngIf`, the base-DOM will be injected. And it will include the script. It's a good thing that it is injected! It's by design, and allows you to have fallback elements to display if Angular doesn't load or if something else goes wrong.